# Qgis project in Lizmap not showing layers, only base layers

Tags: qgis, lizmap

I am following the lizmap tutorial for publish a QGIS project in lizmap but I only see the base layers. Checking and unchecking the layers don't show them. The demo Montpellier project is working well but not my project. Using lizmap 3.1.2 , QGIS 2.18, QGIS Server 2.18.10 on Ubuntu 16.04

[This is my QGIS project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wKMfiC-CYdVEdMSW1lMTRWeEE)

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you solve the problem?
could you write how to...

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a symbolic link inside of your folder?

```
ln -s your_project.qgs /usr/lib/cgi-bin/your_directory/your_project.qgs
```

Is the  `your_project.qgs.cfg` a file?

```
ln -s your_project.qgs.cfg /usr/lib/cgi-bin/your_directory/your_project.qgs.cfg
```

Did you change the permissions in the new directory?

```
sudo chown :www-data /usr/lib/cgi-bin/your_directory -R
```